# Why does my JMeter test run have different numbers of samples

Tags: java, performance, jmeter

I have a JMeter test and when I run this test.

The test includes mostly only GET request

Here I run the test two times:

```
 Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary +      1 in 00:00:06 =    0.2/s Avg:  4601 Min:  4601 Max:  4601 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary +     18 in 00:00:25 =    0.7/s Avg:  9483 Min:  4525 Max: 29202 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =     19 in 00:00:31 =    0.6/s Avg:  9226 Min:  4525 Max: 29202 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    551 in 00:00:30 =   18.1/s Avg: 11589 Min:    67 Max: 59660 Err:   392 (71.14%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =    570 in 00:01:01 =    9.3/s Avg: 11511 Min:    67 Max: 59660 Err:   392 (68.77%)
summary +    189 in 00:00:30 =    6.4/s Avg: 52975 Min:    70 Max: 88945 Err:    42 (22.22%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =    759 in 00:01:31 =    8.4/s Avg: 21836 Min:    67 Max: 88945 Err:   434 (57.18%)
summary +    218 in 00:00:30 =    7.2/s Avg: 95267 Min:   453 Max: 119995 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =    977 in 00:02:01 =    8.1/s Avg: 38221 Min:    67 Max: 119995 Err:   434 (44.42%)
summary +    194 in 00:00:29 =    6.6/s Avg: 126743 Min:   952 Max: 149166 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =   1171 in 00:02:31 =    7.8/s Avg: 52886 Min:    67 Max: 149166 Err:   434 (37.06%)
summary +    209 in 00:00:31 =    6.7/s Avg: 123485 Min:   885 Max: 165675 Err:     7 (3.35%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =   1380 in 00:03:02 =    7.6/s Avg: 63579 Min:    67 Max: 165675 Err:   441 (31.96%)
summary +    227 in 00:00:30 =    7.7/s Avg: 113494 Min:   888 Max: 202528 Err:     6 (2.64%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =   1607 in 00:03:31 =    7.6/s Avg: 70629 Min:    67 Max: 202528 Err:   447 (27.82%)
summary +    264 in 00:00:30 =    8.8/s Avg: 100507 Min:   960 Max: 181355 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =   1871 in 00:04:01 =    7.8/s Avg: 74845 Min:    67 Max: 202528 Err:   447 (23.89%)
summary +    218 in 00:00:30 =    7.3/s Avg: 97068 Min:   909 Max: 156728 Err:     5 (2.29%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =   2089 in 00:04:31 =    7.7/s Avg: 77164 Min:    67 Max: 202528 Err:   452 (21.64%)
summary +    208 in 00:00:29 =    7.1/s Avg: 94552 Min:   650 Max: 143990 Err:     4 (1.92%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =   2297 in 00:05:01 =    7.6/s Avg: 78739 Min:    67 Max: 202528 Err:   456 (19.85%)
summary +    201 in 00:00:32 =    6.2/s Avg: 107602 Min: 81760 Max: 151824 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 548 Started: 750 Finished: 202
summary =   2498 in 00:05:33 =    7.5/s Avg: 81061 Min:    67 Max: 202528 Err:   456 (18.25%)
summary +    210 in 00:00:28 =    7.5/s Avg: 112283 Min: 83132 Max: 150911 Err:     3 (1.43%) Active: 339 Started: 750 Finished: 411
summary =   2708 in 00:06:01 =    7.5/s Avg: 83483 Min:    67 Max: 202528 Err:   459 (16.95%)
summary +    224 in 00:00:31 =    7.3/s Avg: 105992 Min: 61142 Max: 148336 Err:     5 (2.23%) Active: 115 Started: 750 Finished: 635
summary =   2932 in 00:06:32 =    7.5/s Avg: 85202 Min:    67 Max: 202528 Err:   464 (15.83%)
summary +    114 in 00:00:14 =    8.3/s Avg: 124572 Min: 96381 Max: 153037 Err:     2 (1.75%) Active: 0 Started: 750 Finished: 750
summary =   3046 in 00:06:46 =    7.5/s Avg: 86676 Min:    67 Max: 202528 Err:   466 (15.30%)
Tidying up ...    @ Tue Sep 19 13:54:15 BST 2017 (1505825655017)
```

And the second one:

```
    Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary +    475 in 00:01:51 =    4.3/s Avg: 72697 Min:  2707 Max: 106641 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary +    140 in 00:00:35 =    4.0/s Avg: 123952 Min: 106596 Max: 145691 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =    615 in 00:02:26 =    4.2/s Avg: 84365 Min:  2707 Max: 145691 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    240 in 00:00:29 =    8.4/s Avg: 136274 Min: 107411 Max: 164554 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =    855 in 00:02:55 =    4.9/s Avg: 98936 Min:  2707 Max: 164554 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +    111 in 00:01:30 =    1.2/s Avg: 66969 Min:  3932 Max: 197338 Err:    51 (45.95%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =    966 in 00:04:25 =    3.6/s Avg: 95262 Min:  2707 Max: 197338 Err:    51 (5.28%)
summary +    190 in 00:00:27 =    6.9/s Avg: 197033 Min: 179995 Max: 219692 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 750 Started: 750 Finished: 0
summary =   1156 in 00:04:53 =    4.0/s Avg: 111989 Min:  2707 Max: 219692 Err:    51 (4.41%)
summary +    727 in 00:00:28 =   25.5/s Avg: 61250 Min:    66 Max: 205546 Err:   487 (66.99%) Active: 610 Started: 750 Finished: 140
summary =   1883 in 00:05:21 =    5.9/s Avg: 92400 Min:    66 Max: 219692 Err:   538 (28.57%)
summary +    250 in 00:00:30 =    8.3/s Avg: 175360 Min: 81942 Max: 193665 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 360 Started: 750 Finished: 390
summary =   2133 in 00:05:51 =    6.1/s Avg: 102123 Min:    66 Max: 219692 Err:   538 (25.22%)
summary +    359 in 00:00:19 =   19.3/s Avg: 102742 Min: 68901 Max: 192077 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 750 Finished: 750
summary =   2492 in 00:06:10 =    6.7/s Avg: 102212 Min:    66 Max: 219692 Err:   538 (21.59%)
Tidying up ...    @ Tue Sep 19 14:01:48 BST 2017 (1505826108986)
```

No settings changed in between. But why do I have a third more samples in the first run?  Running this on JMeter 3.1 against an EC2 instance. No CPU or memory spikes, also NGINX logs look fine. Also, ame tst duraiton and threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into average response time:

1. `86676` for 1st run
2. `102212` for 2nd run

Therefore you have less samples executed due to increased response time.

If your application under test looks good the bottleneck could be on **JMeter side**, if JMeter is not able to send requests fast enough - response time will be higher. So I would suggest setting up monitoring of CPU, RAM, Swap, etc. on JMeter side as well. You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this.

Also make sure you're following recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide.

Answer (score 0):

I would start worrying about the error rate before looking at the response times.

With such high error rate, check your script first to see if you have variabilized (correlated) required ids, and reproduced correctly the visit.

Then ramp up slowly 100, then 200 .... and check what happens.